# knitr does not inject the R output into a pandoc/markdown documemt

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

I'm trying to use `knitr` to inject R code and its output in `pandoc/markdown` documents. But I do not get knitr to inject the R output. I have tried decorating the R chunks with `r and with`{r}. Both doesn't work. Here my sample setup (with ```r):

First I show the command I issue, then I list the two files subsequently used by this command.

Here the command for the shell:

$ r CMD BATCH knitme.R

Content of `knitme.R`:

```
library("knitr")
pandoc("foo.md")
```

Content of `foo.md`:

````
# My knitr test

```r
1+1
```

Did this print *the result* as well?

Here a graph:

```r

plot(1:10)
```

And where is the graph?
````

After I ran the command I do get, as expected a new file `foo.html`. Here its content:

```
<h1 id="my-knitr-test">My knitr test</h1>
<pre class="sourceCode r"><code class="sourceCode r"><span class="dv">1+1</span></code></pre>
<p>Did this print <em>the result</em> as well?</p>
<p>Here a graph:</p>
<pre class="sourceCode r"><code class="sourceCode r">
<span class="kw">plot</span>(<span class="dv">1</span>:<span class="dv">10</span>)</code></pre>
<p>And where is the graph?</p>
```

This result shows that pandoc converted the input file `foo.md`, *but knitr did not inject the Output of the execeutes R code.

What do I miss? any help appreciated!

Comment: You don't have any knitr code chunks in your document. knitr code chunks in R markdown should start with __```{r}__

Comment: Ok, I have tried it with ```{r} as well, but then I get "{r}" in the html output PLUS still no injected R output from knitr. - I really don't get it: [Yihui describes exactly my approach](http://www.yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/) (Note: Website is pretty flaky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first call `knit()` on an [R Markdown](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/using_markdown) (`*.Rmd`) document, which produces a Markdown (`*.md`) document, and that is when you can run `pandoc()`.

```
library(knitr)
knit('foo.Rmd')
pandoc('foo.md')
```

The R scripts in examples [084](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/084-pandoc.R) and [088](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/088-pandoc-embedded.R) as mentioned on the flaky website have illustrated how. Please also take a look at the Rmd documents to learn the syntax for R code chunks in R Markdown. If you still have 5 minutes, watch the video on the homepage, and I think all the confusion should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for this! Will try it out soon.

Comment: A note about the "flaky website": The DNS resolution of yihui.name doesn't work properly for me, but it *did* work 1-2 days ago. I'm in Australia; I tried different DNS servers, but still no luck. Using the IP address 207.97.227.245, I get from whois, doesn't lead me to the content either (just gives github's 404). - Not sure why I have these DNS issues. So the note was there only to warn others who might have the same problem, *not* as a criticism of the website - sorry if I gave that impression.

Comment: Yep. Works as advertised. Thanks.

Comment: @halloleo No problem! I do not mind whether you meant DNS or the content of the website, but if it was the latter, Github pull requests are [always welcome](http://yihui.name/en/2013/06/fix-typo-in-documentation/)! :)